# Can server side rendering in React be helpful with dynamic presentation?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, architecture, server-side-rendering

**My issue:** For my thesis I am creating an auction site. I have an admin panel in which I would like to have some configurations so that an admin can specify that if there are 10 days before the end of an auction some components should be displayed in different ways, some should be not visible at all etc. That’s what I call dynamic presentation.

**My question:** Right now I am working on architecture and wondering if SSR can be helpful in any way? I am already aware that it can shorten download time of some collections from my database even by half, but I am wondering if there is any way how it can be helpful with dynamic presentation itself?

**What I already know:** I have read all about advantages and disadvantages of ssr or universal rendering in react. Now I am only wondering if it can be in any way helpful with dynamic presentation or it won't matter if I choose SSR or CSR.

**Small side question:** I don’t have the whole architecture ready yet. What I know is that I would like to have a database, one separate app for an admin, backend and frontend (either ssr or csr). My first thought on how to manage this dynamic presentation was to store some rules in the database. Then the rules could be configured in admin app should an admin want to change anything. The rules should be send to backend and calculated with some additional data from frontend. Then backend could send some flag to frontend indicating which components to display etc. In theory I could move calculating to e.g. NodeJs server should I go with SSR. What I'm wondering about is; can you think of any better way to handle dynamic presentation? What I am most afraid of is numerous ifs in the fronetend. I would like to have some more elegant solution but I have no other idea so far. For some time I thought about a scoring system but I believe it would be too complicated (instead of sending a flag, send a score and frontend will display correct things based on the score). Also it wouldn’t solve the issue of ifs on the frontend.

I am aware that on StackOverflow questions which can be answered rather than discussed are preferred but I am really stuck and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically SSR can provide some speed on your page because all of your data will not be trying to be fetched when the react script will end with an API call. Data are fetched from database when page is requested and be passed to the component to render with the script.

Also another very basic advantage and the reason why everyone are going the SSR way is SEO. You cannot achieve SEO page with react CSR. This is because google bot etc will try and crawl your page without even render it. Is like trying to "view source" of a page. When you are in CSR the page has no content only the initial react divs empty. You need SSR to have data on the first request of the user.

SSR brings the data on the first request of the user until a reload. In the meantime react router fetches data from the api.

Let me know if that help you.

PS: also a helpful link https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8